# Cannot navigate to Pages in a .Net Core 3.1 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am looking at a .Net Core 3.1 project, which has one controller and a bunch of pages.  I cannot navigate to any of the pages.  In order to explain my issue; I have added this method to the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Error");
        }
```

If I navigate to the Test method via the browser then instead of redirecting to the error page; the Test method is called in what appears to be an infinite loop i.e. the method is called many times until a 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' page appears.  I think this means there is a routing issue, however I am not sure.  The project has a structure like this:

```
Controllers
Models
Pages 
    Error.cshtml
```

It is a .Net Core 3.1 project.  I have never seen a project with a Pages folder before (it normally says Views) and hence the reason for the question.  I have spent the last hour Googling this and have got nowhere and hence the reason for the question.  I am using .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: Can you post your Error page code? I guess there is redirection in that page as well.

Comment: [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) is a new type of web app introduced in ASP.NET Core 2.0. It doesn't have controllers or views. In ASP.NET Core 3 it became the default type of web app

Comment: To understand what happens, you'll have to look in your browsers developer console > network tab. There should be a request to your test route that's answered with a redirect. Then look what happens next. Look at response > Location header - s.a. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, Error.cshtml has one line in it: <h1>Hello</h1>

Comment: Are razor pages configured in your Startup.cs? i.e. services.AddRazorPages();

Comment: @w0051977 that doesn't explain how the project was created or how it was modified. If you see a `Pages` folder, it means this is a `Razor Pages` web app. It doesn't use controllers. The default `Error.cshtml` doesn't contain `Hello` either. Are you checking someone else's project?

Comment: @w0051977 since you use .NET Core 3.1 just create a new web app with `dotnet new webapp` and check the files.

Comment: @Kavinci, yes that is what it was i.e. AddRazorPages was missing (I have never used Razor pages before).  If you would like to post an answer then I will give some credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Startup.cs file the Razor pages middleware needs to be configured to enable routing for Razor pages.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages()
}
```

It looks like the infinite loop on the Error routing had 2 parts.

1. The route for Test was redirecting to /Error per the controller
2. /Error had no routing which redirected to /Error causing an infinite loop until the runtime stopped execution and threw the error mentioned.